# Maintaining page number across requests

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a button on the client side and when I press, I execute some action on the server and then I call the list method again. Everything works fine but let's say I'm on page 3 and click an item, when the page refreshes it takes me to page 1. I don't know which page I'm on. Is there any way to maintain the page number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the `offset` and `max` parameters through your request. You can pass the current params with the link tag, if you're using it:

```
<g:link action="myAction" params="${[offset: params.offset, max: params.max]}"/>
```

If you're not using `<g:link>`, you can just make them query parameters in your href:

```
<a href="/path/to/action?max=${params.max}&offset=${params.offset}">Link</a>
```

These params need to make it into the `.list()` method in your controller (e.g. `.list(params)`).

As long as the params are set in the action that renders the resulting view, the `<g:paginate>` tag will pick them up and render the pagination links correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass params as

```
<g:link action="myAction" params="${[offset: params.offset, max: params.max]}"/>
```

and

returns params back from controller where you redirect your page as params

```
e.g redirect (action: 'myAction', params: [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
```